# Photoshop - Data sets opening up Camera Raw?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-camera-raw

I have a CSV file with all of the image paths I'm replacing in my photoshop template.

When I preview the rows in the Variables popup most of them work fine, but every once in awhile it pops open the "Camera Raw" program for one of the images that are being inserted and does not give me the preview on the photoshop template with the images inserted.

This also happens when attempting to export data sets to files.

The only difference I can see between the ones that are working and the ones that are opening up Camera Raw is the image size. ( small images do the camera raw popup )

How can I proceed after Camera Raw opens up? What does it want me to do? Can I tell it to use the image and not open up camera raw?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you inserting/placing RAW files into your document?

Comment: @AndrewH I don't even know what a raw file is? They are just PNG files... how do I know if they're RAW files?

Comment: @AndrewH thank you for your response, i got a flow going where every time it pops up i save it as a png then delete the original & rename the new file and it seems to be working. Annoying because I have hundreds of files but at least it's a path forward. I guess some of them were RAW files?

Comment: RAW files are unprocessed image files from a camera, such as .CR2 (Canon), .NEF (Nikon), .ARW (Sony), .DNG (Adobe), etc, etc.  You should check the file extensions to find out what they are, however a PNG is not a RAW file.  RAW files are unprocessed, so the reason they open in Adobe Camera RAW is because they need to be processed first. They aren't technically images until they are processed, they're just RAW data.

Comment: When an image opens in ACR, you can usually just hit Open, and photoshop will continue with its next process, or you can tweak the controls first, for example if you want to brighten up an image, or maybe increase the vibrance, or change the white balance, etc.